# Matplotlib movies from complete figures without using setData

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, movie

I am interested in making movies using matplotlib. Examples I've seen so far, such as [this one for moviewriter](http://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/moviewriter.html), seem to have you editing the data in-place for each frame. This is very efficient, avoiding redrawing the parts of the image that stay the same each time. However, it can be clunky for rapid data exploration. I would like a recipe that lets me simply take a fully drawn figure as each frame (clearing the same figure object each time is fine).

The reason for this: I often create moderately complicated figures using custom functions, with a form like `plotme(ax, data, **options)`. Often I develop these functions without animations in mind, and later want to animate the figures by calling the plotting function in a loop. I don't want to have to change the logic of the functions to "setData" of existing artists in the figure for each frame.

Comment: Nothing about that code requires you to reuse plot objects. You just need a `writer.grab_frame()` whenever you want to capture the current figure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the example code you've shown updates existing plot objects, there is no reason that you need to do so. The critical part of the attached code is the `writer.grab_frame()` which simply gets a screen capture of the current figure.

Here is an example without using existing plot objects

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("Agg")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as manimation

FFMpegWriter = manimation.writers['ffmpeg']
metadata = dict(title='Movie Test', artist='Matplotlib',
                comment='Movie support!')
writer = FFMpegWriter(fps=15, metadata=metadata)

fig = plt.figure()

with writer.saving(fig, "writer_test.mp4", 100):
    for k in range(10):
        # Create a new plot object
        plt.plot(range(k), range(k), 'o')
        writer.grab_frame()
```